# как определить расстояние между двумя координатами на карте PKK5?

Tags: post, get, карты, postgis, росреестр

Ребята, подскажите, пожалуйста, как определить расстояние между двумя координатами на карте [PKK5](https://pkk5.rosreestr.ru/)?

Там есть вот такой сервис (форма для взаимодействия с пользователем, которая принимает GET / POST запросы):

https://pkk5.rosreestr.ru/arcgis/rest/services/Geometry/GeometryServer/distance

Есть поля для ввода from (от) и to (до).
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Для примера, я хочу выяснить расстояние между такими земельными участками, как:

### Кадастровый номер земельного участка №1: **77:03:0002013:5052** Кадастровый номер земельного участка №2: **77:03:0002012:23**

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

**Подробная информация о ЗУ №1:**
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Вот его координаты:

```
{
    "type": "Feature", 
    "properties": {}, 
    "geometry": 
    {
        "type": "MultiPolygon", 
        "coordinates": 
        [
            [
                [
                    [37.797419012925886, 55.81646032139539], 
                    [37.797005069242964, 55.816453861047734], 
                    [37.79700736893009, 55.81639054958373], 
                    [37.796473841516544, 55.8163827971525], 
                    [37.79648074057793, 55.81602618364591], 
                    [37.79695447612615, 55.816035228231755], 
                    [37.796977472997426, 55.81598871319641], 
                    [37.79743051136151, 55.815996465706164], 
                    [37.797419012925886, 55.81646032139539]
                ]
            ]
        ]
    }, 
    "crs": 
    {
        "type": "name", 
        "properties": 
        {
            "name": "EPSG:4326"
        }
    }
}
```

отправляю в форму **from** вот такую запись:

```
{
    "geometryType":"esriGeometryPolygon",
    "geometry":
    {
        "rings":
        [
            [
                [
                    [37.797419012925886, 55.81646032139539], 
                    [37.797005069242964, 55.816453861047734], 
                    [37.79700736893009, 55.81639054958373], 
                    [37.796473841516544, 55.8163827971525], 
                    [37.79648074057793, 55.81602618364591], 
                    [37.79695447612615, 55.816035228231755], 
                    [37.796977472997426, 55.81598871319641], 
                    [37.79743051136151, 55.815996465706164], 
                    [37.797419012925886, 55.81646032139539]
                ]
            ]
        ]
    }
}
```

**и подробная информация о ЗУ №2:**
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
Вот его координаты:

```
{
    "type": "Feature", 
    "properties": {}, 
    "geometry": 
    {
        "type": "MultiPolygon", 
        "coordinates": 
        [
            [
                [
                    [37.79708639832098, 55.81799633847005], 
                    [37.797110545035814, 55.817441816360265], 
                    [37.797216186913225, 55.81736550535963],    
                    [37.79718902185903, 55.81736211375611], 
                    [37.79719204019839, 55.81726036551361], 
                    [37.79771119456739, 55.81726714873805], 
                    [37.79769308453127, 55.817998034244205], 
                    [37.79708639832098, 55.81799633847005]
                ]
            ]
        ]
    }, 
    "crs": 
    {
        "type": "name", 
        "properties": 
        {
            "name": "EPSG:4326"
        }
    }
}
```

и отправляю в форму **to** вот такую запись:

```
{
    "geometryType":"esriGeometryPolygon",
    "geometry":
    {
        "rings":
        [
            [
                [
                    [37.79708639832098, 55.81799633847005], 
                    [37.797110545035814, 55.817441816360265], 
                    [37.797216186913225, 55.81736550535963], 
                    [37.79718902185903, 55.81736211375611], 
                    [37.79719204019839, 55.81726036551361], 
                    [37.79771119456739, 55.81726714873805], 
                    [37.79769308453127, 55.817998034244205], 
                    [37.79708639832098, 55.81799633847005]
                ]
            ]
        ]
    }
}
```

Ввожу в форму эти значения, как описано в [справке](https://tasks.arcgisonline.com/arcgis/sdk/rest/index.html#/Distance/02ss0000007w000000/) , но получаю ошибку **Error Executing Distance**

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

С другой стороны, когда я выполняю example [на другом arggis sample-ресурсе](https://tasks.arcgisonline.com/arcgis/sdk/rest/index.html#/Distance/02ss0000007w000000/), то distance получается вычислить:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: turf.js видели?

Comment: @StrangerintheQ нет, что это такое?

Comment: Джаваскрипт библиотека, которой можно посчитать географическое расстояние без сервера

Comment: @StrangerintheQ а существует нечто подобное на java?

Comment: да, jts - java topology suite https://github.com/locationtech/jts